# configuring babel with webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to configure babel with webpack.  So far I have seen two paths and want to know what is the difference.

**Path1**
in the webpack.config.js file include the following

```
 loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
```

**Path2** in the webpack.config.js include the following

```
 loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
```

and include the following in a separate .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015"
    ]       
}
```

What is the difference between the two what is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the babel config on the loader in your webpack config only applies to webpack, whereas using a `.babelrc` will affect everything that uses babel in any way (e.g. [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) or [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node)).

If you're only using webpack it doesn't make a difference but as soon as you need something that doesn't use webpack, for instance a server or a testing framework in which you'd like to use features that are not yet available in node, you would need to configure babel for that as well.

Using a `.babelrc` is usually preferred as you want to have a general babel config, and if you need to override a setting you can still do that in the specific application like in the webpack config.